# Reference types

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars, terminology, programming-languages, type-theory

Is a reference type (agnostic of PL) the object being pointed at, or the object doing the pointing?

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around the concept fundamentally (of course, I have backgrounds in pointers, C, C++, Java, Prolog, Ocaml, etc. and am familiar with the implementations in all of them).

I mean fundamentally, from a programming languages sense, what exactly is a reference type?

You ask someone what a reference is:

- they might give you the C++ way (essentially a const ptr with implicit dereferences)
- the Java way (objects are references)

but for example, when I have `Dog x = new Dog()`, is the type of the object `Dog` or the type of `x` `Dog` (since fundamentally `x` is NOT the object itself, but a name for it -- which we call a reference to it)

I've tried giving some definitions:

- a reference type is one where there's a many to one mapping of names to objects (vs. one to one for primitives)
- a reference type can be addressed, a primitive cannot (in Java yes, C no)
- you can only gain access to the object types through references (again, doesn't generalize, and which is the `type`?)

I think it's essentially confusing because is the `value` of the type the value of the pointer, or the value of the thing pointed at? You can see how it doesn't quite generalize perfectly, because when you assign, you usually use the pointer's value, but otherwise, that's transparent and you treat it as the guy being pointed at.

It seems to mess up the semantics if you try to say it's a type in which multiple "values" are at play. Which is of that type, the reference or the object (considering the reference points to the object)?

Answer (score 0):

Neither.  A type is not an object.  An object has a type.

Objects don't do pointing.  References do.  A reference type refers to a value that is a reference to an object.

In Java, `int` is a value type.  A `List` or (in your example) `Dog` is a value type.  In `Dog x = new Dog();`, `x` gets assigned the type `Dog`, and the object created by `new Dog()` has type `Dog`.

Comment: What type does the reference `x` have? Is the value of that type the value of the reference or the object?

Comment: @user129393192, `x` has type `Dog`.  `x` is a reference to the object created by `new Dog()`.  "The value of that type" is not a thing -- that phrase doesn't have any meaning.  You can consider the value of `x` to be a reference to the object created by `new Dog()`.

Comment: This is the point I'm unclear on, because the reference and the object itself both cannot have the same type. I'm imagining this in a situation like C, where the "reference" is an `int*` with an associated value and points to an `int`, with an associated value.

Comment: @user129393192, OK, I guess from that perspective, you can think of `x` as having type `ref(Dog)`, and the object created by `new Dog()` as having type `Dog`.

Comment: I guess the problem with that is that `x` has the value of `ref(Dog)` in some circumstances (for example, assignment) but the value of `Dog` in most circumstances. This for me makes the semantics a bit unclear. On the other hand, there is no concrete definition on a `reference type` (which I can't quite figure out), would the Object be the `reference type` or the "reference"? In your answer, you claimed it is the reference, but most (for example in Java) claim that the objects themselves are the reference types.

Comment: For example, in a more "raw" language like C++, these two things could have more distinct types (for example, a ptr to a new piece of memory. The ptr has a distinct type and as does the piece of memory. Here, it seems they "share" that type, which is confusing, since they talk of two separate values.